# nuget error installing protobuf-net on portable library

Tags: nuget, protobuf-net, portable-class-library

I'm trying to install protobuf-net (2.0.0.602) in a portable class library, I just can't seem to get this to work. I get this error:

```
PM> install-package protobuf-net
'protobuf-net 2.0.0.602' already installed.
install-package : Could not install package 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.602'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile4', but 
the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Inspecting the package it appears to target portable-sl4+wp71+windows8, however when i create a vinalla project targeting these frameworks I can't get it to work (profile4 is listed above, but I've tried a few different ones to see what sticks). I've just updated nuget in studio. Running 'nuget' from the package manager console shows the nuget version as 2.1.31022.9038.

If I browse to the protobuf-net.dll within the package (under lib\portable-sl4+wp71+windows8) it will allow me to reference it and all is good.

I can just manually add it, but am I missing something obvious.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be just a slight tweak needed to the nuget config; I had specified `portable-sl4+wp71+windows8`, when actually I needed to specify `portable-sl4+net4+wp7+windows8`, to include regular .NET.

This is fixed in 2.0.0.611, which has been pushed to NuGet.

Comment: And i was trying to repro it  and was wondering how it automatically got fixed, LOL.

Comment: @Deepak you could repro with `PM> Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.602` - probaly not worth doing, though ;p

Comment: cool, nice work. Will test and mark this as answered when I get on my PC :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get this same error for protobuf-net 2.1.0

Comment: same here @ChrisW, i can neither compile master nor install 2.1.0 via nuget :/